# E-mail validation form api

Tags: forms

What is the best way to handle server side e-mail validation in the form API?
Can it be implemented somewhere inside part of the form described below or are there other options?

```
 $form['address']['mail'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('E-mail'),
   '#required' => TRUE,
   '#default_value' => $subscription->mail,
   '#maxlength' => 255,
 ); 

 $form['submit'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => t('Versturen'),
 );

 return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a validation function for your form.  Here is an example using your form. For instance, say your form code is in a function called `my_email`:

```
<?php
function my_email() {
  $form = array();

  $form['address']['mail'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('E-mail'),
   '#required' => TRUE,
   '#default_value' => $subscription->mail,
   '#maxlength' => 255,
  ); 

  $form['submit'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => t('Versturen'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function my_email_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // YOUR CUSTOM VALIDATION CODE GOES HERE
 if (!valid_email_address($mail)) {
   form_set_error('submitted][email_address', t('The email address appears to be invalid.'));
   }
}

function my_email_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // YOUR CUSTOM SUBMIT CODE GOES HERE
}
?>
```

This function will allow you to write custom code to determine if the values entered in your fields are valid or not.  You can also add a custom submit function for your form to execute custom code while the form is being submitted.

Read more about validating forms at [Validating Forms](http://drupal.org/node/751826#validating), submitting forms at [Submitting Forms](http://drupal.org/node/751826#submitting) or read the whole article for a better understanding of the Forms API: [Form API Quickstart Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826)

Comment: There is also a very robust validation function built into Drupal: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/valid_email_address/6

Answer (score 5):

Instead of adding a form validation handler to the form, you can add a validation handler to the form element that needs to be validated: Use [#element_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#element_validate), which accepts an array of validation handlers that will be applied to the form element.

```
$form['email'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Email',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#element_validate' => array('myelement_email_validate')
);
```

The validation handler receives three arguments: The form element being validated, the `$form_state` and the `$form` array for the form containing the form element. The validation handler should call [form_error()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_error/7) or [form_set_error()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) to report any validation error.

```
function myelement_email_validate($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  $value = $element['#value'];
  if (!valid_email_address($value)) {
    form_error($element, t('Please enter a valid email address.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: [#element_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#element_validate) is not a custom property, but a Drupal property. The show code is fine, and it is a valid alternative to what proposed from other answers, including the one suggesting a solution that is valid only for the Webform module.

Comment: One of the advantages of using @nmeegama's approach is that it makes your code look much clearer, instead of having everything in one large validate().

Comment: Another advantage of using @nmeegama's solution is that the field can be reused in other forms as well without the need to re-validate.

Comment: You can also reuse the code elsewhere, which is nice if you have the same validation for multiple elements.

Answer (score 3):

Explained here: http://drupal.org/node/279127

```
<?php
$mail = $form_values['submitted_tree']['email_address'];
if (!valid_email_address($mail)) {
  form_set_error('submitted][email_address', t('The email address appears to be invalid.'));
}
?>
```

Comment: The linked page is showing the solution for the Webform module.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8 It can be validated by the following code.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Validate email
  if (!\Drupal::service('email.validator')->isValid($form_state->getValues()['email'])) {
     $form_state->setErrorByName('Email', $this->t('Email address is not a valid one.'));
  }
}
```

There's interface for that since 8.7 https://www.drupal.org/node/2997196

Reference : https://www.drupal.org/node/2912661

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [Elements](https://www.drupal.org/project/elements) module and just use the 'emailfield' in the #type property of form element, just like this:

```
 $form['YOUR_FIELD_KEY'] = array(
    '#type' => 'emailfield',
    '#title' => t('Email'),
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#description' => t('Enter a valid email'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
```

Just that easy with elements module, make custom validation for a simple email field does not have sense, you do not have to reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 0):

Install [Email Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/email) module and patch it with the [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/970068#comment-9457181) on comment 16. Then use the code in the linked issue description to define your email field with built-in validation:

```
$form['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'email',
    '#title' => t('Email'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => "",
    '#description' => "Please enter your email.",
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 20,
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

Email address can be validated with your form validate handler

If function `your_form` defines your form then default validate handler would be `your_form_validate` or otherwise you can also set it manually

```
 $form['#validate'] = array('callback_to_validate');


 function your_form_validate($form, $form_state){
   if(!filter_var($form_state['values']['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
     form_set_error('email', t('Invalid Email Address'))
 }
```